# Count rows within SQL Rank Window based on condition

Tags: sql

| session_id | rank | url_path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 | /topic/aaa |
| 001 | 2 | /topic/aaa?type=3 |
| 001 | 3 | /topic/aaa?type=4 |
| 001 | 4 | /topic/aaa?type=5 |
| 001 | 5 | /essay/e1 |
| 001 | 6 | /payment_processing |
| 001 | 7 | /essay/e2 |
| 002 | 1 | /topic/bbb |
| 002 | 2 | /topic/bbb?type=3 |
| 002 | 3 | /topic/bbb?type=4 |
| 002 | 4 | /topic/bbb?type=5 |
| 002 | 5 | /topic/ccc?type=4 |
| 002 | 6 | /topic/ddd?type=4 |
| 002 | 7 | /essay/e3 |
| 002 | 8 | /essay/e4 |
| 002 | 9 | /payment_processing |
| 002 | 10 | /essay/e5 |

I have a table like this and I have to count how many essays urls were visited before a payment step. Expected output should be something like

| session_id | essay_count_before_payment |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 |
| 002 | 2 |

I have tried a few things and stuck. Really appreciate some help

Comment: Please provide relevant details on what exactly you tried and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: can you share your coding attempt at this problem? @SanathSastry

Comment: I have solution but it seems like a dirty solution, the question is closed and is not accepting answers. The code is long to post it as a comment here.

Answer (score 1):

```
with data as (    
    select session_id,
        case when url_path like '/payment%' then
            count(case when url_path like '/essay%' then 1 end)
                over (partition by session_id order by "rank") end as cnt
    from T
)
select session_id, max(cnt) from data group by session_id
```

It's not clear how you would handle multiple payments in a single session. This will return the count of all essays leading up to the final payment.

```
select session_id,
    (
        select count(*) from T as t2
        where t2.session_id = t1.session_id and t2."rank" < t1."rank"
            and t2.url_path like '/essay%'
    ) as cnt
from T t1
where url_path like '/payment%'
```

This second query would return a count for every payment.